# Books similar to The Calculus Diaries

Tags: reference-request

Does anyone know of popular maths/physics books similar to The Calculus Diaries, where the author, Jennifer Ouellette, is a science/maths writer rather than a scientist/mathematician?

Comment: "How Not to Be Wrong" is written by a mathematician, but it is pretty easy to follow for a non-mathematician.  Same for "Innumeracy" and "A mathematician Reads the Newpaper."  "The Drunkards Walk" is written by a long-time science writer and not a mathematician.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions!